# Surprise function in information theory

Tags: probability, information-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two events and $p$ and $q$ be their corresponding probabilities. 
One of the properties of surprise function is:

$$S(AB) = S(A) + S(B)$$

Which seems to be fine if the two events are independent.

However, let's take following example:
$A$ indicates getting an odd number when rolling a dice and $B$ indicates getting $3$ when rolling a die. 
These two events are clearly dependent. How does the above property works? because clearly $P(AB)$ is not equal to $(1/6)*(1/2)$. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is a "surprise function"?  Do you mean "probability measure" instead?  What do you mean by $AB$?  Do you mean $A\cup B$ or $A\cap B$ instead?  For $Pr(~)$ a probability measure, you do have that if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events then $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)$ (*and more generally, this is true if and only if $A\cap B$ is an "impossible" event, i.e. occurs with probability zero*) and you have that $A$ and $B$ are *independent* events if and only if $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.

Comment: The more generalized statements for each is the inclusion-exclusion principle $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$ and the multiplication principle $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B\mid A)$ or equivalently $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(B)\times Pr(A\mid B)$ (*which is just a rearrangement of the definition of conditional probability*).

Comment: I apologize for not making it clear. Given a random variable Y, S(Y) = -log[P(Y)]. And AB = A ∩ B.

Comment: $S(A\cap B)=-\log[P(A\cap B)]= -\log[P(A)\times P(B\mid A)]= -\log[P(A)]-\log[P(B\mid A)]= S(A)-\log[P(B\mid A)]$ is equal to $S(A)+S(B)$ if and only if $\log[P(B\mid A)]=\log[P(B)]$ if and only if $P(B\mid A)=P(B)$ which is true if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.  Your "surprise" function does *not* have the stated property generally and in fact $S(AB)\neq S(A)+S(B)$ whenever $A$ and $B$ are not independent.  This all comes again from the multiplication principle, definitions of independence, and basic properties of logarithms.

Comment: This formula clearly can't be true in general, since if B = A, you have S(AA) =2S(A). And S(Odd Even) = S(Odd)+ S(Even), but S(Odd Even) should be infinity.